# Get first/last name, city, etc from facebook, google login?

Tags: asp.net, owin, asp.net-identity-2

When implement external login for Facebook/Google. The following code can get email. Is it possible to get First name, Last name, City, etc.?

```
// loginInfo has the type of Microsft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.ExternalLoginInfo
var loginInfo = await Microsoft.Owin.Security
                      .AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

See the following link I think you may get more information from fb.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/get-more-information-from-social-providers-used-in-the-vs-2013-project-templates.aspx.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on